# Disabling product alerts - effect on existing alerts

Tags: magento-1.9, product, stock, alert

We have had product stock alerts in place and some customers have set up alerts. If we disable alerts what happens to existing alerts?

Comment: What do you mean by `some customers have set up alerts` ? what do you want to do exactly

Comment: Some customers have set up product stock alerts for when items come back in stock. If we now disable alerting (config>sytem>catalog>product alerts) what happens to those alerts  that have already been set up? Are they deleted? Are customers going to be left thinking they will get alerted but actually no emails will be sent?

Comment: Yes, if you disable it, customers will not be notified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Short answer**: Mail won't sent to anyone in any case.

Magento uses cronjobs to send out these alert emails. If you are interested in, you can check out the core module `Mage_ProductAlert`. Here you can see the cronjob is defined inside its `config.xml` file like this:

File : `app\code\core\Mage\ProductAlert\etc\config.xml`

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <catalog_product_alert>
            <run>
                <model>productalert/observer::process</model>
            </run>
        </catalog_product_alert>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

Now if we check out `productalert/observer::process()` method. it looks like this:

File : `app\code\core\Mage\ProductAlert\Model\Observer.php`

```
public function process()
{
    $email = Mage::getModel('productalert/email');
    /* @var $email Mage_ProductAlert_Model_Email */
    $this->_processPrice($email);
    $this->_processStock($email);
    $this->_sendErrorEmail();

    return $this;
}
```

As you can see, `$this->_processPrice($email)`and `$this->_processStock($email)` is what we need to really looking into. In both these methods, you can see a checking like this:

`productalert/observer::_processPrice()`

```
if (!Mage::getStoreConfig(
     self::XML_PATH_PRICE_ALLOW,
     $website->getDefaultGroup()->getDefaultStore()->getId()
 )) {
     continue;
 }
```

`productalert/observer::_processStock()`

```
 if (!Mage::getStoreConfig(
     self::XML_PATH_STOCK_ALLOW,
     $website->getDefaultGroup()->getDefaultStore()->getId()
  )) {
      continue;
  }
```

As you can see, it checks whether the alert is enabled or not. If it is deactivated, it will not send emails.

**PS**: As soon as you enable it later, there is a chance to send out emails at that time. If you want to completely avoid this, you need to clear `product_alert_price` and `product_alert_stock` tables.

Comment: Great answer @Rajeev. Can I just empty the product_alert_stock table or are there links to other tables that I need to consider? Is it best write some code to do this or can I just do it using sql?

Comment: if you truncate the tables in my answer then there won't be any emails sending any more. You don't need to touch any other tables. This is because Magento uses these tables internally to keep track and send product email alerts. It is safe to truncate those tables via a direct SQL query. Make sure it just truncate those two tables only. Never touch any other table or do not delete those two tables. Just truncate it.